# How do i do a format check? so the input is in the correct format. E.g. dd/mm/yy. (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net

[image: How do i do a format check? so the input is in the correct format. E.g. dd/mm/yy. (Visual Basic)]
How do i do a format check? so the input is in the correct format. E.g. dd/mm/yy. (Visual Basic)

Answer (score 3):

I've long said the best way to see if a value is in the correct format is to actually *try to parse it*. This has the advantage of being a *perfect* validation check, instead of merely a heuristic, as well as giving you an instance of the target type to work with, which is usually the next step anyway.

Therefore I suggest [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0). Here's a basic example:

```
Dim input As String = " ... "
Dim result As DateTime
Dim format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
If DateTime.TryParseExact(input, format, Nothing, Nothing, result) Then
    ' The input is in the correct format
Else
    ' The input is NOT in the correct format
End If
```